# how to solve %d outputs in my printf show the ascii values of num1, num2, and sum, instead of their assigned values

Tags: c, vim, putty

here is my code. Just trying to make a simple calculator in C.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main( void ) //initialize code
    {
         int num1 = 0 ; //first number
         int num2 = 0 ; //second number
         int sum = 0 ; //sum of num1 and num2

     printf("Enter the first number: " ) ;
     scanf( "%d", &num1 ) ; //first number inputted by user


     if (num1 < 0) //if the user entered number is negative
     {
          do //ask them to enter a non-negative number until it's positive
          {
               printf( "Enter a non-negative number: ") ;
               scanf( "%d", &num1 ) ;
          }
          while ( num1 < 0 ) ; //loops until num1 >= 0
     }

     printf( "Enter the second number: " ) ; //initialized after if loop ends
     scanf( "%d", &num2 ) ; //second number inputted by user

     if (num2 < 0) //if the user entered number is negative
     {
          do //ask them to enter a non-negative number until it's positive
          {
               printf( "Enter a non-negative number: ") ;
               scanf( "%d", &num2 ) ;
          }
          while ( num2 < 0 ) ; loops until num2 >= 0
     }
     sum = (num1 + num2) ;
     printf( "ADDITION\n" ) ;
     printf( "The sum of %d and %d is %d", &num1, &num2, &sum ) ;
}
```

When I run a.out and punch in 3 for num1 and 2 for num2, I get

ADDITION
The sum of -7316 and -7320 is -7324

This doesn't really make sense, and I'm assuming this is just the ASCII values rather than the ones I assigned.

I'm a total beginner and just need a little bit of help, Google hasn't helped much.

Comment: `printf( "The sum of %d and %d is %d", &num1, &num2, &sum )` -> `printf( "The sum of %d and %d is %d", num1, num2, sum )`

Comment: VTC as typo....

Answer (score 2):

Using unary `&` operator, you are passing *addresses* to the variables (not ASCII values) to `printf()`. Remove them and pass *values* of the variables like this:

```
printf( "The sum of %d and %d is %d", num1, num2, sum ) ;
```

Comment: OH. Easy fix. Thanks!